# How to create server side pagination for SPA using express and mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, pagination

I am new to Node.js and i'm trying to create single page pagination on server side, using Express and MySQL, if possible. Right now, all that i have succeeded is to create multi-page.I am using Jade as template engine. I know that i can create it on client side, but considering that i need to use AJAX request for doing it, i don;t get any performance boost for doing it like that.

```
//GET DATA FROM DB WITH OFFSET!!!
Users.prototype.get_offset_data  = function(page_number, category, plans) {
    let blocksize = 12;
    let cat;
    let offset = (page_number - 1) * blocksize;
    let plan = plans ? `where json_extract(plans, '$.${plans}') = true` : '';
    if (plan === '') {
         cat = category ? `where category = ${category}`: '';
    } else {
         cat = category ? `and category = ${category}`: '';
    }
    let query = `select  *  from  test_video_category   ${plan} ${cat} limit  ?  offset  ? `;
    console.log(query);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.conn.query(query,[blocksize, offset], function(err,rows){
            if(err) reject(err);
            return resolve(rows);
        });
    });
};
//GET COUNT OF ALL ELEMENTS FROM DB!!
Users.prototype.get_limited_data_page_number = function(category, plans) {
    let cat;
    let plan = plans ? `where json_extract(plans, '$.${plans}') = true` : '';
    if (plan === '') {
        cat = category ? `where category = ${category}`: '';
    } else {
        cat = category ? `and category = ${category}`: '';
    }
    let query = `select count(*) as row_count from test_video_category  ${plan} ${cat}`;
    console.log(query);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.conn.query(query, function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
};

//SEND DATA TO NEW PREVIEW PAGE
router.get('/new-preview-page', function (req, res, next) {
    let page_number = req.query.page_number;
    let category = req.query.category;
    let plans = req.query.plans;
    try {
        req.getConnection( async function (err, connection) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            let Users = new users(connection);
            let offset_data = await Users.get_offset_data(page_number, category, plans);
            let count_data = await Users.get_limited_data_page_number(category, plans);
            if (offset_data && count_data) res.render('marketplace', {offset_data: offset_data, count_data: count_data});
        });
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have a more specific question or a reason why stuff does not work? At first glance the code seems on the right way. You receive the current offset number, query the database for the next X according to offset, then send back the response. Sidenote: An SPA is a Single Page App, so if you render a new page containing plan 11-20 instead of overwriting the original page for 1-10 client side, you do not have an SPA, you have a normal multi page website. The performance boost in an SPA comes from only having to AJAX data between the client and the server, instead of full pages.

Comment: The stuff does work as a multi-page, but i need to create it as a single page. So my question is, is there a way to do that on server side, or should i just create new route and use res.send or res.json, to send data to client side, and create whole spa there?

Comment: Yes, else you don't have an SPA. If you need to make an SPA, move the rendering over to client side and have your express send the next x plans to the client as JSON. Then the client can use that data to replace the currently rendered plans with the ones the database just send back by just applying the rendering template to the new plans it received and replacing or updating the existing node.

Comment: For the record, you could also send pre-saturated jade html chunks instead of JSON or full pages and then skip client side rendering, but then you lose alot of the performance benefits an SPA has, since the server will still have to do most of the calculations and rendering. But then technically it's also an SPA, just one I would never pay for as an end user.

Comment: Okay, thanks for help :)

Comment: Hey, i have another question which i hope that you can help me with. Now i need now to move this whole req.Connection to separate function, from try block, and wrap it into new promise, and then just to pass that new function to this try block, but when i move it, i get an error that req.Connection is not a function, so could you give me some advice on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to add `req`, `res` and `next` as parameters to the new function you created, so you can use `try { seperateFunctionName( req, res, next ); } catch(){}`? Not sure what you mean by wrapping it in a promise, since `async function (err, connection) {` already returns a promise ( that resolves with undefined unless there's an error ) due to the async keyword.

Comment: Yeah, but then, page_number, category and plans are undefined.

Comment: I succeeded, thanks for the help.